# Как уменьшить снизу и сверху картинку в ImageView?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Создал меню и меня интересует как уменьшить картинку снизу и сверху, т.к. там много пустого пространства. Картинки 72х72, хранятся в Drawable, от папок с разными разрешениями отказался, что бы не занимали много места + в landscape ориентации, это у же другой layout, они масштабируются нормально. android:scaleType перепробывал все. Вот код:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<include layout="@layout/title"/>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bg_button">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:scaleType="centerInside"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/homeButtonText" android:layout_below="@id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/buttonFont"
                        android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:scaleType="centerInside"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/homeButtonText" android:layout_below="@id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/buttonFont"
                        android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/availableButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/availableButton"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:scaleType="centerInside"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_available_g"/>
            <TextView   android:id="@+id/availableButtonCounter" android:layout_alignTop="@id/availableButton" android:layout_alignRight="@id/availableButton"
                        android:text="2234" android:visibility="gone"
                        style="@style/buttonBadge"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/availableButtonText" android:layout_below="@id/availableButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      style="@style/buttonFont"
                      android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_available"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:scaleType="centerInside"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/homeButtonText" android:layout_below="@id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/buttonFont"
                        android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:scaleType="centerInside"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/homeButtonText" android:layout_below="@id/homeButtonLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/buttonFont"
                        android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_main">



</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Вот как получается:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно использовать вес(атрибут android:layout_weight), а точнее соотношение. Например 1 к 3. То бишь одной вьюхе задается вес равный 1, другой 3. Либо можно использовать даже дробные значения, тогда место будет сжато. Вообще, использование веса - один из самых гибких способов позиционирования компонентов. Не считая новые лэйауты. Но тогда вам придется переписать весь ваш макет, так как вес используется только в LinearLayout-е.
2. Можно поиграться с атрибутом ImageView scaleType или adjustViewBounds="true". Поставить fitXY в scaleType, но тогда картинки могут быть расплющены.

Пробуйте. Вариантов много.

Comment: Спасибо! adjustViewBounds="true" немного уменьшило общую высоту. scaleType я пробывал все, ничего не годится и fitXY тоже пробывал. Менять все на LinearLayout-ы не выход. Может еще как нибудь немного уменьшить общую высоту можно?

Comment: Честно говоря не могу разобрать в вашем коде что есть что, но можно попробовать уменьшить вес с 0.2 до 0.15 там где у вас эта полоска с картинками. А вообще, запутанно как-то у вас все. Перепишите на более простую схему - вам же проще будет сопровождать, да и будущему читателю кода.

Comment: Спасибо большое, изменение веса не помогло, оставлю как есть пока...